# Is NSDateFormatter available in Swift 3?

Tags: swift3, nsdateformatter

I am trying to use it in my code after using DatePicker but no suggestions are coming for NSDateFormatter and only DateFormatter is coming.
If anyone has used in their code, kindly share it here.
Also, what changes should i make in order to receive the suggestions.

I want to change the format from MM-DD-YYYY to DD-MM-YYYY.

Comment: let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "DD-MM-YYYY"
let newDate   =   dateFormatter.date(from: "23-03-2017") // String to Date()
let dateStr =   dateFormatter.string(from: Date()) // Date in String.

Use the above code for Swift 3.

Comment: It isn't working. Thank you anyway. :)

Comment: Can you share sample input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        //format in which recived Date Present
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy"
        let newDate = dateFormatter.date(from: "20-MAR-2017")
        // format to which you need your date to convert
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM-dd-yyyy"
        if let newDate  = newDate{
            let dateStr = dateFormatter.string(from: newDate) 

            print(dateStr) //Output: MAR-20-2017

        }
```

Comment: Tried this as well. Output is correct as you had given but not working in the project.  Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3 has dropped NS prefix, so you wont get suggestion for `NSDateFormatter`. `DateFormatter` is same as `NSDateFormatter`, just the name is changed. You can use `DateFormatter` in same way you have been using `NSDateFormatter`. Check [SE-0086](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0086-drop-foundation-ns.md) proposal for more details.